# How to reduce background noise in the video

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audio-quality

I am creating a video tutorial to upload into youtube , but after recording with the help of camtasia i am unable to remove the noise form the video.

Note : I am able to remove the system noise like clicks etc., but unable to remove the noise created by vehicles outside my home.

Is there any way to develop quality videos in this scenario

Comment: 2nd Mario's comment. For getting rid of recorded audio noise you might want to try [ProTools | First](http://www.avid.com/pro-tools-first) freeware, but many video editing software packages have some basic audio editing tools including filters for low mid and high range. If there's a bus going by as someone is talking, however, there's really not much you can do to get rid of it. Otherwise, sound proofing during recording might help some, as well as turning off loud appliances like refrigerators, or using a directional or near field mic (like a lapel mic).

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/do-i-need-an-audio-recorder/18900#18900) (and the [video link](http://nofilmschool.com/2015/08/24-sound-basics-will-help-you-lay-sturdy-foundation) included within it) tells you all you need to know.

The long and the short of it is that good audio is essential to good video, and getting good audio requires its own set of techniques, practices, considerations, and, in many cases, gear.

Sound attenuates at a 1/(r^2) rate for point sources.  Unfortunately, an automobile roaring through your walls functions more like a area source, not a point source, and thus decays very little from one end of the room to another.  Nevertheless, a headset can put a microphone very close to your mouth, and that can push the room noise floor down fairly far.  You might also consider making videos between the hours of 2AM and 4AM, when vehicular traffic is minimal.

Comment: Any recommendations for a good headset mic, for this scenario?